# What's the difference between uint32 and i32 in webassembly data types?

Tags: web, computer-science, webassembly

I do not understand what is the difference between a uint32 and i32. Definitions follows as given below:

[image: uint32]

[image: i32]

Also, only instructors should have opcodes, and what is the meaning of **"Type constructor"** here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of `uintN`, `varuintN`, and `varintN` are concepts exclusive the WebAssembly's [binary format](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md). They're purely there to encode WebAssembly in a compact machine-readable format.

`i32` and friends are [language types](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md#language-types). The [semantics of WebAssembly](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Semantics.md#types) have a better description of these types and how they interact. Basically, they exist at the language level and form the basic datatypes that are usable in a WebAssembly program.

They're at two totally different levels. It's kind of like C `int` versus the ASCII encoding used for C source code. One's purely at the language level, and another is purely used when representing that language in its stable format (for C: source `.c` files; for WebAssembly: binary `.wasm` files).

"Type constructor" is just the type that corresponds to the particular binary value in the binary format: you need some binary value that you encode each type with. Going back to my C source example, a source character capital B would be encoded as `0x42` in ASCII. Well here a WebAssembly `i32` type is encoded as the byte `0x7f`.

Comment: From my understanding, if I find a byte '0x7f' in a wasm binary file, it means there must some kind of integer value around this place?

Comment: Thanks! I think i understand this. : )

Comment: No, if you find `0x7f` it could mean many things because the WebAssembly format is a variable-length encoding. `0x7f` can mean different things depending on context. This is the same as in x86, where each byte can mean different things depending on the instruction being decoded.